# Unable de-serialize object from DB4O

Tags: java, serialization, enums, deserialization, db4o

does anybody experience this kind of exception during reading object from DB4O?
Or can you please explain what can goes wrong? It seems to me it has problem with de-serialization of Enum object but don't understand why since I tried on sample project to serialize/de-serialize same object and it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

**Exception in thread "main" com.db4o.ext.Db4oException: JDKField java.lang.String:name**
    at com.db4o.reflect.jdk.JdkField.handleException(JdkField.java:82)
    at com.db4o.reflect.jdk.JdkField.set(JdkField.java:64)
    at com.db4o.internal.reflect.StrictFieldAccessor.set(StrictFieldAccessor.java:17)
    at com.db4o.internal.FieldMetadata.set(FieldMetadata.java:830)
    at com.db4o.internal.FieldMetadata.activate(FieldMetadata.java:641)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler$2.processAspect(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:92)
    at com.db4o.internal.metadata.MarshallingInfoTraverseAspectCommand.processAspect(MarshallingInfoTraverseAspectCommand.java:52)
    at com.db4o.internal.metadata.StandardAspectTraversalStrategy.traverseAllAspects(StandardAspectTraversalStrategy.java:24)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.traverseAllAspects(ClassMetadata.java:2118)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.traverseAllAspects(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:256)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.activateAspects(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:95)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.activate(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:118)
    at com.db4o.internal.Handlers4.activate(Handlers4.java:300)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.instantiateFields(ClassMetadata.java:1355)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.activate(ClassMetadata.java:1289)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.instantiate(ClassMetadata.java:1247)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.UnmarshallingContext.read(UnmarshallingContext.java:70)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.read(ObjectReference.java:306)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.readForActivation(ObjectReference.java:136)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.activateInternal(ObjectReference.java:132)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.processedByImmediateActivation(ObjectContainerBase.java:1857)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.stillToActivate(ObjectContainerBase.java:1833)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readObject(AbstractReadContext.java:83)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readAtCurrentSeekPosition(AbstractReadContext.java:48)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext$1.run(AbstractReadContext.java:40)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.SlotFormat.doWithSlotIndirection(SlotFormat.java:64)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readObject(AbstractReadContext.java:38)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.read(AbstractReadContext.java:30)
    at com.db4o.internal.FieldMetadata.read(FieldMetadata.java:793)
    at com.db4o.internal.FieldMetadata.activate(FieldMetadata.java:639)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler$2.processAspect(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:92)
    at com.db4o.internal.metadata.MarshallingInfoTraverseAspectCommand.processAspect(MarshallingInfoTraverseAspectCommand.java:52)
    at com.db4o.internal.metadata.StandardAspectTraversalStrategy.traverseAllAspects(StandardAspectTraversalStrategy.java:24)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.traverseAllAspects(ClassMetadata.java:2118)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.traverseAllAspects(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:256)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.activateAspects(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:95)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.activate(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:118)
    at com.db4o.internal.Handlers4.activate(Handlers4.java:300)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.instantiateFields(ClassMetadata.java:1355)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.activate(ClassMetadata.java:1289)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.instantiate(ClassMetadata.java:1247)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.UnmarshallingContext.read(UnmarshallingContext.java:70)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.read(ObjectReference.java:306)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.readForActivation(ObjectReference.java:136)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.activateInternal(ObjectReference.java:132)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.processedByImmediateActivation(ObjectContainerBase.java:1857)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.stillToActivate(ObjectContainerBase.java:1833)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readObject(AbstractReadContext.java:83)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readAtCurrentSeekPosition(AbstractReadContext.java:48)
    at com.db4o.internal.OpenTypeHandler.read(OpenTypeHandler.java:175)
    at com.db4o.internal.Handlers4.readValueType(Handlers4.java:309)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readAtCurrentSeekPosition(AbstractReadContext.java:50)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext$1.run(AbstractReadContext.java:40)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.SlotFormat.doWithSlotIndirection(SlotFormat.java:64)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readObject(AbstractReadContext.java:38)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.read(AbstractReadContext.java:30)
    at com.db4o.internal.FieldMetadata.read(FieldMetadata.java:793)
    at com.db4o.internal.FieldMetadata.activate(FieldMetadata.java:639)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler$2.processAspect(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:92)
    at com.db4o.internal.metadata.MarshallingInfoTraverseAspectCommand.processAspect(MarshallingInfoTraverseAspectCommand.java:52)
    at com.db4o.internal.metadata.StandardAspectTraversalStrategy.traverseAllAspects(StandardAspectTraversalStrategy.java:24)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.traverseAllAspects(ClassMetadata.java:2118)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.traverseAllAspects(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:256)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.activateAspects(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:95)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.activate(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:118)
    at com.db4o.internal.Handlers4.activate(Handlers4.java:300)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.instantiateFields(ClassMetadata.java:1355)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.activate(ClassMetadata.java:1289)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.instantiate(ClassMetadata.java:1247)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.UnmarshallingContext.read(UnmarshallingContext.java:70)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.read(ObjectReference.java:306)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.readForActivation(ObjectReference.java:136)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.activateInternal(ObjectReference.java:132)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.processedByImmediateActivation(ObjectContainerBase.java:1857)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.stillToActivate(ObjectContainerBase.java:1833)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readObject(AbstractReadContext.java:83)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readAtCurrentSeekPosition(AbstractReadContext.java:48)
    at com.db4o.internal.OpenTypeHandler.read(OpenTypeHandler.java:175)
    at com.db4o.internal.Handlers4.readValueType(Handlers4.java:309)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readAtCurrentSeekPosition(AbstractReadContext.java:50)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext$1.run(AbstractReadContext.java:40)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.SlotFormat.doWithSlotIndirection(SlotFormat.java:64)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.readObject(AbstractReadContext.java:38)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.AbstractReadContext.read(AbstractReadContext.java:30)
    at com.db4o.internal.FieldMetadata.read(FieldMetadata.java:793)
    at com.db4o.internal.FieldMetadata.activate(FieldMetadata.java:639)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler$2.processAspect(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:92)
    at com.db4o.internal.metadata.MarshallingInfoTraverseAspectCommand.processAspect(MarshallingInfoTraverseAspectCommand.java:52)
    at com.db4o.internal.metadata.StandardAspectTraversalStrategy.traverseAllAspects(StandardAspectTraversalStrategy.java:24)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.traverseAllAspects(ClassMetadata.java:2118)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.traverseAllAspects(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:256)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.activateAspects(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:95)
    at com.db4o.internal.handlers.StandardReferenceTypeHandler.activate(StandardReferenceTypeHandler.java:118)
    at com.db4o.internal.Handlers4.activate(Handlers4.java:300)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.instantiateFields(ClassMetadata.java:1355)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.activate(ClassMetadata.java:1289)
    at com.db4o.internal.ClassMetadata.instantiate(ClassMetadata.java:1237)
    at com.db4o.internal.marshall.UnmarshallingContext.read(UnmarshallingContext.java:70)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.read(ObjectReference.java:306)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectReference.read(ObjectReference.java:292)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase$8.apply(ObjectContainerBase.java:901)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase$8.apply(ObjectContainerBase.java:899)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.asTopLevelCall(ObjectContainerBase.java:431)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.readActivatedObjectNotInCache(ObjectContainerBase.java:899)
    at com.db4o.internal.query.result.AbstractQueryResult.activatedObject(AbstractQueryResult.java:35)
    at com.db4o.internal.query.result.AbstractQueryResult$1.map(AbstractQueryResult.java:63)
    at com.db4o.foundation.MappingIterator.moveNext(MappingIterator.java:30)
    at com.db4o.foundation.Iterable4Adaptor.moveNext(Iterable4Adaptor.java:46)
    at com.db4o.foundation.Iterable4Adaptor.hasNext(Iterable4Adaptor.java:28)
    at com.db4o.internal.query.result.StatefulQueryResult.hasNext(StatefulQueryResult.java:42)
    at com.db4o.internal.query.ObjectSetFacade.hasNext(ObjectSetFacade.java:61)
    at com.example.main.RunMe.main(RunMe.java:70)
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final java.lang.String field java.lang.Enum.name to com.db4o.reflect.generic.GenericObject**
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at com.db4o.reflect.jdk.JdkField.set(JdkField.java:62)
    ... 110 more

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody will face similar issue in future, I finally find the root cause. I serialized the object "Person" with enum "Status" as property in DB4O. Once I tried to read it I used following:

```
ObjectSet<Object> allObjectsFromDb4o = db4OConnection.queryByExample(null);
```

to get all objects and sync them with my in memory storage. However I misunderstood how the data are serialized... so basically not only my object "Person" but also enum "Status" was persisted. So when I tried to read all objects from DB4O and afterwards cast them into my "Person". Once I de-serialized "Person" object retrieved by query everything was fine... but than I tried to cast enum "Status" retrieved by same query and in that moment I get upper mentioned weird exception. 
Hope will help somebody ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar exception with db4o.

In my case I had stale class definitions in the persistent store.  I deleted my stale database file and then I was able to write and read as expected.

If you are in the early stages of development and you don't have "real data" yet, perhaps you can do likewise.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes(objects) are done in the Databank.db40 will give you some kind of exception. I got the error of IllegalArgumentException.

In that case, just backup the old Databank.db40, delete the file from the current directory and run the file.

I was using Netbeans Application for building the JAVA Project.